# Best way to manage events bound to game time in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I am working on a game and need several events to start at specific game time (enemy spawning at night, changes in npc behavior and etc.) The first idea I had was to put an if statement in update function of game manager to check for specific time points and launching the events I need. It works fine, but I do not think that it is correct approach.

I found little information about this situation. Somebody proposes to use corutines for timed events, but I don't think that I will be able to tie them to the game time as the game time can be paused, slowed down or opposite. I am new to Unity and C# and thus trying to find the correct way for efficient code and easy maintenance. Need your help :)

Answer (score 0):

For your purpose like you describe, time line (or animation) in unity can be a solution for you.
This video will explain how to use time line.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G_uBFM3YUF4